# Magento 2 not showing categories or add products

Tags: magento2

I added category and subcategory to magento 2 and after that I finished. I reindexed and flushed cash but nothing appears on the website frontend - only the old categories. I tried many times clearing cash and reindexing but it was in vain. Any ideas?

Comment: Any one have a solution

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked Enable Category and Include in Menu enabled? they should be set to yes or green in order to show on frontend like image below.

[image: enter description here]

Comment: Yes i did . But nothing the newly added category never appear on frontend